# count on column filter by where greater than

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Can anyone let me know the correct MySQL syntax for below please

```
SELECT ta.id, 
       ta.raw,
       ta.title, 
       ta.hits as tag_hits, 
       it.hits as image_tag_hits,

       (SELECT count(*) 
        FROM image_tag 
        WHERE image_tag.tag_title_id = ta.id) as tag_count
FROM tag_title ta
INNER JOIN image_tag it ON ta.id = it.tag_title_id
INNER JOIN image im ON it.image_id = im.id
WHERE im.id = '12975' AND tag_count >0;
```

Many thanks

Comment: `HAVING tag_count>0`. but better approach will be JOIN with subtable

Comment: why is a join with a subtable a better approach

Comment: Faster - 1 subquery instead of X subqueries for every tag. Check my answer.

Answer (score -1):

try with `having`:

```
SELECT ta.id, ta.raw,ta.title, ta.hits as tag_hits, it.hits as image_tag_hits,
(SELECT count(*) from image_tag where image_tag.tag_title_id = ta.id) as tag_count
FROM tag_title ta
INNER JOIN image_tag it ON ta.id = it.tag_title_id
INNER JOIN image im ON it.image_id = im.id
WHERE im.id = '12975' 
group by ta.id, ta.raw, ta.title, ta.hits, it.hits
having tag_count >0;
```

You may do this as well, if you want to keep `where`:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ta.id, ta.raw,ta.title, ta.hits as tag_hits, it.hits as image_tag_hits,
    (SELECT count(*) from image_tag where image_tag.tag_title_id = ta.id) as tag_count
    FROM tag_title ta
    INNER JOIN image_tag it ON ta.id = it.tag_title_id
    INNER JOIN image im ON it.image_id = im.id
    WHERE im.id = '12975' )X
   WHERE X.tag_count >0;
```

Comment: You don't need a `group by` as I have mentioned the `having` in my answer. Group by is added additional. I doubt that needs a downvote :$

Comment: still why `group by ta.id, ta.raw, ta.title, ta.hits, it.hits` in answer?

Comment: He can remove if he wants Peter, it's a pity that MYSQL is pretty forigiving in terms of `aggregation functions`, so as a norm, I keep the `group by`. Stressing again, if OP wants he can remove it.

Comment: I still don't know why `group by` if there is no aggregation function in your query (i am not talking about subquery)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski I have explained why I used group by here. My answer is correct, infact both approaches are. I just dont have enough time to give a sqlfiddle OP. So I still *don't know why a downvote*...

Comment: @Mathew, please try both approaches in my answer and comment `=)`

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski post a question!

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski everyone here is to contribute and share, as well as to learn. I have stated clearly the reason of me adding group by. If you are not happy with please do post a question, so perhaps, one could help you. Chip it off. Try writing the same query in SQL Server or Oracle - which I have clearly mentioned in an above comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this::

```
SELECT 
ta.id, 
ta.raw,
ta.title, 
ta.hits as tag_hits, 
it.hits as image_tag_hits, 
count(ta.id) as tag_count 
FROM tag_title ta 
INNER JOIN image_tag it ON ta.id = it.tag_title_id 
INNER JOIN image im ON it.image_id = im.id 
INNER JOIN image_tag ON image_tag.tag_title_id = ta.id
WHERE im.id = '12975'
GROUP BY ta.id having tag_count >0
```

Comment: he wants `COUNT(*)` from `image_tag` not `tag_title`

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: If you Look CLosely to the table structure, `ta.id`
is equal to  `image_tag.tag_title_id`
So while doing the inner join, count on both the column will give the same result

Comment: **it's not equal** i believe it's 1-to-many relationship, this is why he is using COUNT(*) He may have 1 row in `tag_title` and 100 rows in `image_tag`

Comment: its a many to many relationship. an image can have many tags and a tag can belong to many images. the image_tag table is the many part of the relationship

Answer (score -1):

**I don't know how your DB looks like but I believe you are looking for that solution:**

```
SELECT
    ta.id, 
    ta.raw,
    ta.title, 
    ta.hits as tag_hits, 
    it.hits as image_tag_hits,
    COUNT(*) as tag_count
FROM
    image_tag it
LEFT JOIN
    tag_title ta ON
    ta.id = it.tag_title_ID
LEFT JOIN
    image im ON it.image_id = im.id
WHERE
    im.id = 12975
    # not need for tag_count=0, because if there is no image_count there will be no row :)
GROUP BY
    it.tag_title_id
```

---

And there is your query (fixed)

```
SELECT
    ta.id, 
    ta.raw,
    ta.title, 
    ta.hits as tag_hits, 
    it.hits as image_tag_hits,
    tcount.tag_count
FROM
    tag_title ta
LEFT JOIN
    ( 
    SELECT 
        tag_title_id,
        count(*) as tag_count
    FROM 
        image_tag 
    GROUP BY
        tag_title_id
    ) tcount ON tcount.tag_title_id = ta.id
INNER JOIN image_tag it ON ta.id = it.tag_title_id
INNER JOIN image im ON it.image_id = im.id
WHERE im.id = '12975' AND tcount.tag_count >0;
```